# How to know if the android project build was triggered by Android Studio or command line?

Tags: android, gradle

Is there a way to tell if the build / run was activated by the execution button or from the Android Studio command line?

I want to check some native reaction files when I create a version to publish, but not when I run the project because I have the native reaction server running. The idea is not to create a release version if I forget to create a reactive native bundle

Comment: could be possible to distinguish them by adding some arg, but why?

Comment: you mean you can't find run button?

Comment: I want to check on some react native files when I build release, but not when I just run the project because then I have the react native server running. the idea is to not build a release version if I forget to build react native bundle

@MuhannadFakhouri args seems like a good solution to this!

Comment: By running gradlew command you can pass gradle args like this `gradlew COMMAND -P{KEY}={VALUE}`

Comment: thanks! that should do it!